# What will be the best way to get data from some blocs?

Tags: flutter, dart, architecture

I use that structure for getting data from blocs.

```
class CheckOutBloc extends Bloc<CheckOutEvent, CheckOutState> {
  CheckOutBloc(
      {@required this.orderRepository,
      @required this.addressBloc,
      @required this.cartBloc})
      : super(null);

  final MyOrderRepository orderRepository;
  final AddressBloc addressBloc;
  final CartBloc cartBloc;

  @override
  Stream<CheckOutState> mapEventToState(
    CheckOutEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is CreateOrder) {
      try {
        yield CheckOutInProgress();
        final address = (addressBloc.state as AddressLoadSuccess).getPrimary();
        final items = (cartBloc.state as CartLoadSuccess).items;

        final Map<String, dynamic> order = {
          'items': items.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
          'addressUUID': address.uuid,
          'description': '',
          'storeUUID': items[0].uuid,
        };
        await orderRepository.createOrder(order);
        yield CheckOutLoadSuccess();
      } catch (_) {
        yield CheckOutFailed(_?.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I think, It is not better way to get data.
I think get data using stream of bloc like `bloc.listiner(() => add())` or use repository provider where we send request to another bloc for getting data of other blocs. I can't decide which way is the best.

How you think which way is better or my option is good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from the info given. If you see all the data needed from addressBloc and from CartLoadSuccess in your ui, I would maybe send the data via the event.

It also depends on the complexity of your app and if complexity increase and data store changes in the future are likely. If not, you may also think of a repository shared by different blocs. On the other hand, if costs from requests and network traffic play a role, I guess I would use the event or your approach shown (though you may have to catch situations where the other bloc has an unexpected state (still in progress or with error)